# Notify user of inadequate role ASP.NET MVC 4 simplemembership simplerole

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I am using ASP.NET MVC4 SimpleMembership and SimpleRoleProvider to determine authorization before exposing certain methods.

For example:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Corporate")]
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
     //some code
     return View(model)
}
```

If the user is not in the "Admin" or "Corporate" role (or their session has expired), they are correctly sent to the /Account/Login page.

However, one tester brought up a good point that once on this Login page, there is no hint as to why the user was sent here.  If they simply aren't authorized to access the page they are trying to access, they keep logging in again and again and thinking the site is broken.

Ordinarily, I would add a property to the model or pass an optional parameter in the url with a message such as,

```
You do not have adequate permissions to access that page.  
Please log in as an administrator.
```

or something to that effect.  However, because the filter happens before they enter the method, where / how would I add the message?

Comment: Now you're leaking information. A) that page exists B) there's an Administrator role.

Comment: A better way to accomplish this would be to not allow the user to perform the task in the first place, such as not sending the full menu when the user logs in so they don't even know the link exists.

Comment: Ok, but still it is a common use case that the user does have the admin or corporate role, and their session hasn't expired (so they can navigate the site) but the SimpleRoleProvider forgets their role (something that DOES happen).  When they get to the login page, they are still going to be puzzled as to why they have to log in again.  It is just confusing to not explain this to them.

Should I just go into the controller, try to check their role and redirect from there?